# Return XML object as String in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, vba, recordset

I am currently half way through a project where I am migrating data from an ancient Adobe Workflow server using Visual Basic and COM (component object model).

I am trying to pull an XML object from a record set in VB and place it in an XML file (data.xml). The problem is when I try to print it to an external file I get an error that says...

```
"Cast from type 'IXMLData' to type 'String' is not valid."
```

My existing code is...

```
    'Open a recordset
    record = conn.Execute(SELECT xmldata FROM WorkItems)

    'Open the FileSystemObject objFs 
    objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Open a textstream (objTextStream) to virtual created file 
    objTextStream = objFs.CreateTextFile(locationStr, True)

    'Store and concatinating content into a variable
    strWriteString = "<?xml version=\1.0\encoding=\UTF-8\?>" & vbCrLf

    Dim recordXml = record.Collect(0)
    Do While Not record.EOF
        strWriteString = strWriteString & "<dummy>" & recordXml & "</dummy>" & vbCrLf
        record.MoveNext()
    Loop
    record.Close()
```

I have tried to set the object as a String but that didn't work, and as I'm in Visual Studio 2003 I am finding it hard to add the necessary libraries. Can anyone point me in the right direction as what to do?

Answer (score 1):

In the database, what is the type of the first column? In other words, what is the type of recordXml? Apparently it is not something that can be converted directly to String. Find out the data type and then you can figure out how to convert it.

It might help if you use Option Explicit with your application, requiring variables to be declared.